# Call to a member function Count() on a non-object in

Tags: php, pdo

index.php

```
$user= DB::getInstance()->get('users',array('user_id','=','1'));
if(!$user->Count()){
    echo 'No User'; 
}else{
    echo 'User Exists';
}
```

DB.php

```
class DB {
    private static $_instance = null;
    private $_pdo,
    $_query, 
    $_error = false,
    $_results,
    $_count = 0;
    public function Count(){
        return $this->_count;
    }
}
```

get function

```
class Yapilandirma{
    public static function get($yol = null){
        if($yol){
            $yapilandirma = $GLOBALS['yapilandirma'];
            $yol = explode('/',$yol);
            foreach($yol as $bit){
                if(isset($yapilandirma[$bit])) {
                    $yapilandirma = $yapilandirma[$bit];
                }
            }

            return $yapilandirma;
        }

        return false;
    }   
}
```

I checked other 15+ topics with same title but i couldn't solve it.need add more detail to post still it wants detail omg.

Comment: I have found answer here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33162167/fatal-error-call-to-a-member-function-count-on-a-non-object-in-not-solved?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Count` is a method of the `DB` class. But you're setting `$user` to the result of `get()`, not `getInstance()`.

```
$instance = DB::getInstance();
$instance->get('users',array('user_id','=','1'));
if (!$instance->Count()) {
    echo 'No user';
} else {
    echo 'User exists';
}
```

Comment: You haven't posted the `get` method. Does it set `_count`?

Comment: i dont know i follow a video tutorial. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PaBWDOBFxDc&list=PLfdtiltiRHWF5Rhuk7k4UAU1_yLAZzhWc

Comment: So you're just copying code without understanding what it does? I'm not interested in tutoring someone who doesn't know the basics of what they're doing.'

Comment: And I'm not going to watch a 20 minute video to figure out what you're doing. Sorry.

Comment: i checked its _count no any $_GET method form.

Answer (score 0):

I ran across this tutorial and had the same problem as user had, & I eventually gave up. I worked for a long time on it but was never able to figure it out. If someone wants to take a swing at it I would post the fix to other discussion board and help out a bunch of people. The tutorial is awesome and the system is great but there just seems to be a lingering problem that eventually hangs alot of people up.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PaBWDOBFxDc&list=PLfdtiltiRHWF5Rhuk7k4UAU1_yLAZzhWc

public function count() {

return $this->_count;
}

the actual word count is in bold blue..whereas the rest of the function names are in just regular black font. even if you don't want to take the time to look at the videos can some at least tell why that is????? I'm using notepad ++

Comment: Because `count()` is an actual function in PHP and Notepad++ has most PHP functions bold blue font.